# Regex for decimal value and 1 letter

Tags: regex, vba

I need a regex that will collect product numbers (any combination of 1 - 99999.99999 or 99999.99999A/Z). I need to check .cells(i, 1).value and make sure that it only contains a numeric value or a numeric value and 1 letter at the end of it and nothing more.

```
Dim RegEx As New RegExp
Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "^\d+\.?\d+?[a-z A-Z]$|^\d+\.?\d+?$|^\d+?[a-z A-Z]"
```

The pattern above collects every cell that has either a whole number or decimal and anything that comes after it.

I need "123.2A" | "123" | "1234A" and not "123.2All this extra text"

Comment: `^\d{1,5}(?:\.\d{1,5})?[A-Z]?$`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v2sBw7/1).

Comment: What if the input is `123.2:All this extra text`? Do you still want to extract `123.2`? I'd suggest [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/oPJFFj/1) then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pattern without alternations `|`.

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-zA-Z]?(?!\S)
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digit with an optional decimal part
- `[a-zA-Z]?` Match an optional char a-zA-Z
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hii8aN/1).

Answer (score 0):

I have no affiliation with this site, but appreciate that it provides an easy way to test to see if a regex is doing what you want...  https://regex101.com/

I just entered your regex and your test strings (one per line).  Since I believe you do not want to match "0" and do want to match upper and lower case letters, I changed Demo's regex to `(?i)^[1-9]?\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,5})?[A-Z]?$`.  See if that's doing what you intended.